# Nhibernate Named SQL Query

Tags: nhibernate, named-query

Can any body tell me what is wrong with below query Named SQL Query using *NHibernate*.
As I am getting error - "Error in Named Query : GetSecondReviewIncomeStatements ":

```
 <sql-query name="GetSecondReviewIncomeStatements" read-only="true">
 <![CDATA[
  SELECT I.TotalNetSales,I.CostOfGoodsSold,I.GrossProfit
  FROM IncomeStatement as incomeStatement
  INNER JOIN FETCH CompSearchResultItem as resultItem
  ON incomeStatement.Comparable.ID = resultItem.Comparable.ID
  AND resultItem.CompSearch.ID = :compSearchID     
  ]]>-->
 </sql-query>-->
```

I have searched a lot on the web, some say instead on `On` put `Where`.
I also tried `NamedQuery` only but everytime I get the same error.

Comment: are you Using Stored Procedure with Nhibernate.?

Comment: Please share the sample code, only sample , dont put entire Code

Comment: What is the extra --> after ]]> ??

Comment: Ok..are you intending to use hql or sql for your query? (either way, you have syntax errors). If it's hql, you should be using a <query> not a <sql-query> mapping.

Comment: your query is has errors. For example where is `I` defined? And how can an SQL query contain expressions like `incomeStatement.Comparable.ID`? I think you are looking to use `HQL`, for which the tag is `<query></query>`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the Format for Named Query in **.hbm.xml** file.

**in hbm.xml**

```
     <sql-query name="ShowProducts">
        <return alias="Product" class="Product" />
        exec ShowProducts
      </sql-query>

<sql-query name="DeleteProducts">
    <query-param name="Id" type="int"></query-param>

    exec DeleteProducts @ID=:Id
  </sql-query>
```

**in Code Usage**

```
 IQuery query = (IQuery)session.GetNamedQuery("ShowProducts");


        var listProducts = query.List<Product>();

        GridView1.DataSource = listProducts;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your SQL runs if you put it 'as-is' in your rdbms sql executor?

Besides the strange `-->` after the enclosing `CDATA` element, I've noticed that you haven't declared the `I` alias in your query.

I mean, these columns preceded with `I`...

```
SELECT I.TotalNetSales,I.CostOfGoodsSold,I.GrossProfit
```

...are coming from where?